# How to check why I'm getting 401 error with nginx and spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, logging

I have standard Spring Boot application which is exposing few endpoints.
One of them is endpoint for upload a file (multipart request).
On Virtual Machine I'm using nignx as proxy which points to my Spring Boot Application.
When I call all endpoints using postman it works just fine. The same for my Java component.

But now I have to synchronize my component with another external team.
They faced a big problem - multipart request does not work in only one single case.
When they are trying to call it from their JS application from their VM (locally it works just fine). All another reuqests work correctly locally and from VM.
They are getting 401 resposne without any body from nginx server.
I turned on debug mode for Spring Security module but my component does not see this request not at all.
The only log has nginx in access.log and it looks like this one:

```
111.111.111.11 - - [13/Sep/2021:12:41:33 +0000] "POST /my/api/file/upload HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "-" "-".
```

How can I debug why nginx is getting this error if there is no log on Spring Boot App?

Answer (score -1):

The destination you are post to may need some authorised party, try to add below lines in your `application.properties` file

```
security.basic.enable: false
security.ignored=/**
```

Comment: Sure it needs some. But authorization part works just fine when we call this endpoint using postman or locally (developer machine). So how disabling security will help me in this case?

Comment: You can check the application.properties file in your endpoint settings, set the security.basic.enable: false disabling security will help or not.

Comment: or your endpoint should  allow your IP to get through  the endpoint by firewall settings.